# Receiving a pickled stream in golang

Tags: python, serialization, go

I have my tcp server in golang and would like to receive and decode a pickled stream

I am using [stalecucumber](https://github.com/hydrogen18/stalecucumber) to unpickle data in go

The python side roughly looks like this

```
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',5006))
sock.send(cPickle.dumps(data))
```

The Go server looks like this:

```
ln, _ := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_PORT)
conn, _ := ln.Accept()
data := make([]byte,0)
for {
    // for gob I would normally do this
    //  dec.Decode(&data); 
    err := stalecucumber.UnpackInto(&data).From(stalecucumber.Unpickle(<can't provide conn here>))
}
```

Any way to listen to a stream of pickled objects and decode them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From stalecucumber
>   `Unpickle` needs a `io.reader`
>
> ```
> func Unpickle(reader io.Reader) (interface{}, error) {
> ```
>
> Should look like that:
>
> ```
> err = UnpackInto(&data).From(Unpickle( bytes.NewReader( buf.Bytes() ) ))
> ```

I assume you have to use it with `conn`

```
err = UnpackInto(&data).From(Unpickle( bytes.NewReader( conn ) ))
```